# Swatches from watercolor

Tags: adobe-illustrator, swatches

I need to create my own swatches. From my own watercolor.

For this I traced my watercolor.

How can I create swatches from this traced watercolor for Adobe Illustrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your expanded trace, then go to the swatches panel and in the flyout menu click on "New Color Group..."